# I can not watch any videos on youtube

Tags: windows-7, youtube

I can not watch any videos on Youtube with any browser ( Chrome 20 , Firefox 13 , IE 8 ). I get this error
`An error accurred. Please try again later.`

My OS is Windows 7 (32bit) and the antivirus is zonealarm extreme security 10.1.079.000 .

I installed flash player 11 but no success. I exited zone alarm to watch video, but no success again and error is the same. I don't know what's the problem . I searched a lot but didn't find the problem.

I'd appreciate any idea.

Comment: I had a very similar problem no youtube even after reinstallation of Flash. I solved it by flushing the browser's cache (CTRL+SHIFT+<ELETE)

Comment: I had similar problem too,I must uninstall flash 11,remove all registry records connected with flash player and after that I install flash 10. Its not good to upgrade your flash player once it works.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this:

1. Temporarily disable popup blocking software installed on your computer to test.
2. Allow YouTube.com as a trusted site in your Firewall software.
3. Ensure other applications like Quicktime, iTunes, Real Player, or Windows Media Player aren't set as the default streaming application, as this might affect the video player.
4. Make sure your computer is set up properly for Flash by checking out [Adobe's Advanced Troubleshooter](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56115)

Answer (score 0):

Flash 11 and Chrome aren't playing nicely together ATM, especially with YouTube Videos. I suggest entering "chrome://plugins" in your address bar, and press enter. The very first plugin you should see is flash, if not, hit "details" on the right then disable all versions of flash 11. Most of the time, a version of 10 will still be available.... To go further, I would even uninstall flash 11 and download a legacy version of flash from adobe then install that. Chrome will automatically pickup the plugin on the next launch...